# Return distinct nodes in repeated node paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been trying to return most frequent 2 to 5 event paths in Neo4j by count of paths, but the thing that I struggled with was to return paths with only distinct event names.

What I was trying to achieve is e.g if the most common path is 
web visit->web-visit->web visit with the count of 3000 and the second most common path is 
web visit->web visit with the count of 2000 
then what I would see is just 
web visit - 5000 as I only care about the distinct event types and not the repeated chains.
Equally if the most frequent path is 
web visit->bill payment->web visit->web visit with the count of 3000
What I would like to see is
web visit->bill payment->web visit -3000

```
MATCH path = (:event)<-[:PREV*2..5]-(:event)
UNWIND nodes(path) as n
RETURN collect(distinct n) as nodes,count(path)
```

The query runs for ages and then times out eventually, so I am not getting any results from it.

Comment: Your match pattern is looking for segments, so you're going to see subsegments be counted multiple times if they are part of larger patterns. So for example, a three :event segment, if it occurs in a chain of 5 or more events, will be counted multiple times, one for a length of 2, another for a length of 3, up until 5. And also counted for multiple times in every combination with its neighbor nodes. So if you have an event chain of :PREV with ids like [1,2,3,4,5], then you'll have these results: [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5].

Comment: Also what differentiates a "web visit" from a "bill payment" and other event types? What property of :event nodes are you looking at?